# org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException

Tags: eclipse

I'm getting this error when i transfer xml fie in eclips env

```
12:29:58,946 FATAL [main] Main  - No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/ANU_DOC/MyWS/xslt/file1/source.xml
org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/ANU_DOC/MyWS/xslt/file1/source.xml
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:186)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I guess it correctly, your code doesn't have proper reference to XSL file. You need to verify if you are referring properly to XML and XSLT files in your code.

Or post your Java code (probably a 5 line code(max)) which invokes transformation. 
How are you referring XML and XSL source code is important here..

I am posting sample code for your reference:

Here input.xml and input.xsl are files residing in the bin folder. (Or in the same location as of `.project` file if you are running it from Eclipse IDE)

```
 TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("input.xslt")));
 Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));
 transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
```

Sample Code 2:
(here XSL code is passed as string)

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
String sxslt = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">    <xsl:output indent=\"no\" />    <xsl:template match=\"@*|node()\">        <xsl:copy>            <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*|node()\"/>        </xsl:copy>    </xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";
StringReader xslReader = new StringReader(sxslt);
Source xslt = new StreamSource(xslReader);
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));
transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
```

Comment: Hi,Am not writing any JAVA code for transformation. I was doign in Note pad++ by using XMl tool pligin and now i want to call java method insie xml so am using eclips env

Comment: am able to do it now.. this was happening because i added new JAXP over there i removed it and its working fine now.. and if i call a method inside my xml file am getting

14:34:01,696 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker - Cannot find class 'java:com.xslt.date.GetDateNow'.

Answer (score 0):

am able to do it now.. this was happening because i added new JAXP over there i removed it and its working fine now.. and if i call a method inside my xml file am getting

```
14:34:01,696 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Cannot find class 'java:com.xslt.date.GetDateNow'.
```